# What are the optimal video settings for spotting infantry?

Tags: pc, battlefield-3

I'm finding it difficult to spot enemy soldiers (dang camo!) and I wondered if there are certain video settings that can improve how soldiers show up.

Here are my current settings (not limited by hardware):

[image: BF3 Video Setttings]

*Mesh Quality* looks to be the only setting that says it affects draw distance, but increasing it also adds more clutter.

Comment: I remember reading somewhere that stated that graphics quality will in no way create advantages for players. I'll have to look for an official quote.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I *believe* this is covered in the Johan Andersson Battlefield 3 Presentation tech talk at the NVIDIA GeForce Lan 6. He indicated that no settings are ever so low that they confer an advantage (e.g. disabling all trees, etc.)

It's in part 5 at about 1:15 seconds in.

> In a multiplayer game you can't just disable everything. Because that increases the visibility too much. If you disable all our particles and all our shadows it becomes like Quake 3 arena. And that's not really fair.

The other parts: [one](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KMaL6j7Ry6c), [two](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UAgWi6hQ0Mk), [three](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EN549g0GNgc), [four](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=20ZYkYiCdrg).

I would shoot for mostly High settings, as that is what the designers intended. (I do recommend turning shadows to medium and avoiding MSAA as the perf penalties are far too high for very little visual improvement.)

Comment: Excellent videos - going to experiment with those `Render.PerfOverlayVisible` and `Render.DrawFps` console commands.

Answer (score 0):

Keep everything on Low. Set Anisotropic Filtering 16x anti aliasing-post and deferred on medium. Change Field of View (FOV) to 90. This should make you have best visibility possible IMO.

Comment: AA will blur everything, thus cause less visibility. You need to see every PIXEL out there, not smudge them into the background. Changing FOV will only change how much you see far away from the center, not the depth.